# xdata and ydata must be the same length

Tags: python

I am trying to get my plot of temperature data to update by replacing the past 10 iterations with the next 10 as seen in the code before but I keep getting a "xdata and ydata must be the same length" error. Along with fixing the error, is this the best way to do such a task of replacing a certain amount of old data with new data on a real time plot? Note: there is a little more code in the file but it is just for opening and reading the labjack equipment

```
temperature = []
x = list()
y = list()
x1 = list()
y1 = list()

# Read loop
for i in range(60):
    # Get the thermocouple reading on AIN0. 
    tempC = ljm.eReadName(handle, "AIN0_EF_READ_A")
    temperature.append(tempC)
    dT = temperature[i]-temperature[i-1]

    if -.5<dT<.5:
        print "Temperature:","%.3f"% temperature[i],"         " "dT:", "%.3f"% dT, "         " "Steady State" 
        sleep(1)
    else:
        print "Temperature:","%.3f"% temperature[i],"         " "dT:", "%.3f"% dT
        sleep(1) 

    x.append(i)
    y.append(temperature[i])

    x1.append(i)
    y1.append(dT)

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    li, = ax.plot(x,y)


    # draw and show it
    fig.canvas.draw()
    plt.show(block=False)

    # loop to update the data
    while True:
        try:
            y[:-10] = y[10:]
            y.append(temperature[i])

            # set the new data
            li.set_ydata(y)

            fig.canvas.draw()

            sleep(1)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            break
# Close handle
ljm.close(handle)
```

Comment: I think what you want is simply `y.append(temperature[i])` noting that the `append` adds the item to the list (`y` is a list).

Comment: I think that is what I have now. In the line marked error I have y[-10:] = y.append(temperature[i])

Comment: No, you have an *assignment* to `y[-10:]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This statement is the problem:

```
y[-10:] = y.append(temperature[i]) <-- error
```

Because the right-side of that statement is an iterable (`y.append(_something_)` returns a `None` type, so this is equvalent to:

```
y[-10:] = None
```

You could do

```
y[-10:] = [None]*10
```

But I don't think that's what you want, I think you've already sliced your list and now you just want to add another value to it, right?  If so, then just drop the left-side of the statement so you end up just doing the `append`:

```
y.append(temperature[i])
print(y)  # Should display the new value last in the list
```

Comment: When I replaced y[-10:] = y.append(temperature[i]), I got an error that said  "xdata and ydata must be the same length."

Comment: Please revise your question to include your current attempted code, I'll look at it this evening, because I don't think that error should raise in that case.

Comment: OK, so it's also important to post the full traceback of the error, and indicating which line it's raising on! The line I added *didn't* cause the error :) I believe (unfamiliar with this, but seems reasonable guess) that the error is raised in your plotting module, and that's because you're changing the size of your `y` list but not making same change(s) to the `x` list. Does that make sense? You probably just need to also do `x.append(_something_)` but I don't know what that something should be.

Comment: What I recommend at this point if you can't debug it on your own -- because the scope of this problem is *solved*, is to either upvote or accept this answer as helpful, and ask a new question *specific* to your plotting error.

Comment: thank you! your argument certainly makes sense to me. unfortunately I may have to stick with this plotting because I need a way to do real time plotting while updating the data every certain amount of data points. This is the only way I have found to do that.

Comment: Right, I'm not saying the error is a bug in your plot module, but that the error is happening because you're sending the plot module un-balanced lists. You need to make sure that `x` and `y` lists (assuming these are points to plot on Cartesian plane, etc.) are the same length!

Comment: Currently, I see you are `append` to the `y` list, you're slicing the `y` list, etc., are you doing the same transformations to the `x`?

Comment: I am not sure how to slice my x like I did my y. I am essentially making my x just the empty list of i values (0-1000) so I need to somehow splice up the x like I did the y to update as I have gotten my y values to. I tried a similar code to my x as I did my y but I am getting the same error.

Comment: I tried x[:-10] = x[10:]  followed by the x.append(i)   but got the same error

Comment: Right, well, like I said I don't know what this module is, what it's supposed to do, or what the arguments are supposed to be, you're wasting your time on this with me, because as I've already mentioned i can't help you with this *new* problem, so you should do one or both of the following: **1)** upvote or accept this answer (because I did solve your original error) **2)** Ask a new question specifically pertaining to the x/y error you're getting in this module so that *others* who might know something about it can help you with it.